# Trying to use gnu awk in windows 10 to split a large sequence file

Tags: batch-file, awk, cmd

I am trying to use the GNU `awk` command in windows to split a large sequence file to make it easier for processing but I am not sure how to translate the `awk` command in order to work in windows. I am using `gawk`.

This is the command I am trying to run:

I have tried to escape with double quotes but something else is not working

```
awk 'BEGIN {n_seq=0;} /^>/ {if(n_seq%1000==0){file=sprintf("myseq%d.fa",n_seq);} print >> file; n_seq++; next;} { print >> file; }' < sequences.fa
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: Windows CMD probably can't cope with single quotes. A common workaround if you can't get rid of Windows entirely is to put the Awk script in a file and call it with `awk -f file sequences.fa`

Comment: Personally I would install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) (or on Win10 you could consider intalling Ubuntu, from the Microsoft Store) and do your awk there so you don't have to monkey with porting things like this to make windows command line happy.

Comment: @tripleee *"... if you can't get rid of Windows completely."* 

Comment: @tripleee that was the quickest option and worked just fine. Thank you very much for all the answers, all constructive. 
I would get rid of windows if I could, but in this case, it is a uni teaching room, so not much space for personal options/opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (under Command Prompt):

```
awk 'BEGIN {n_seq=0;} /^^^>/ {if(n_seq^%1000==0){file=sprintf("myseq%d.fa",n_seq);} print ^>^> file; n_seq++; next;} { print ^>^> file; }' sequences.fa
```

When put into a `.bat` or `.cmd` **batch file**, use this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {n_seq=0;} /^^^>/ {if(n_seq%%1000==0){file=sprintf("myseq%%d.fa",n_seq);} print ^>^> file; n_seq++; next;} { print ^>^> file; }' sequences.fa
```

#### Another way is like this(under Command Prompt):

```
awk "BEGIN {n_seq=0;} /^>/ {if(n_seq%1000==0){file=sprintf(\"myseq^%d.fa\",n_seq);} print >> file; n_seq++; next;} { print >> file; }" sequences.fa
```

Or **in batch file** like this:

```
awk "BEGIN {n_seq=0;} /^>/ {if(n_seq%%1000==0){file=sprintf(\"myseq%%d.fa\",n_seq);} print >> file; n_seq++; next;} { print >> file; }" sequences.fa
```

Tested with [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FePhyFoFum/phyx/master/example_files/pxbpseq_example/Sequences.fa) and changed the `1000` to `3`.

From `cmd /?`:

```
The special characters that require quotes are:
     <space>
     &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~
```

But usually the problem is at `&<>|%`.
When using double quotes, you need to be careful which parts are in a pair of double quotes, which parts are not. In above example, `myseq%%d.fa\` are considered without quotes.